# react leaflet shown as an overlay

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

It's my first time using react leaflet. I have coded as I understood. But the leaflet map is shown multiple times and isn't limited to a box as I want.

This is my code.

```
<div id="map-container" style={{ height: 200 }}>
    <Map center={position} zoom={8}>
        <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
        />
            <Marker position={position}>
                <Popup>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br />Easily customizable.</Popup>
            </Marker>
    </Map>
</div>
```

I want to place this map inside a fixed sized div. But instead it's shown as below and can be moved all over the screen by clicking.

[image]

If there is anyone who can help me, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you import `leaflet.css`? Please provide a reproducible example to get more help.

Comment: Oh, yeah, after you asked, I tried it and worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Basically this problem occurred due to CSS
> Simple Copy and Paste This Link in Your **PUBLIC/INDEX.HTML**

```
  <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.3/leaflet.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the first comment helped me. I had forgotten leaflet.css file.